# Non-empty closed subset of the complex plane is the spectrum of a normal operator

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

This is an exercise in Chapter 13 of Rudin's Functional Analysis. The question is to show that every non-empty closed subset of $\mathbb{C}$ is the spectrum of some normal (not bounded) operator in a Hilbert space $H$ if dim $H=\infty$.

Does the question ask whether we find a normal operator for every infinite dimensional Hilbert space, or does it ask for the existence of some normal operator on some Hilbert space whose spectrum is equal to the given non-empty closed set?

I would be grateful for hints on this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All separable Hilbert spaces are isomorphic, so it doesn't really matter which Hilbert space you use.  That said, you might as well use one that is convenient: in this case, one that is connected in some way to the closed subset.  That's one hint.  Another hint: multiplication operators are normal.